# PowerShell Get-Netadapter hangs

Tags: powershell, raspberry-pi, windowsiot

I have a PowerShell script that is run at boot. It is designed for a small site server running on a Raspberry Pi3.

One of the things it does is reset the network settings. The following commands hang however in some situations.

```
$Adapter = Get-NetAdapter | ? {$_.Status -eq "up"}
$Interface = $Adapter | Get-NetIPInterface -AddressFamily "IPv4"
$Interface | Set-NetIPInterface -DHCP Enabled | Out-Null
$Interface | Set-DnsClientServerAddress -ResetServerAddresses | Out-Null
```

I was looking for any help as to why it might hang, a different way of coding resetting the Network Adaptor to DHCP or a way in which I can catch the hang (it does not error)

Comment: It typically hangs on the first or the last line of the lines above.

Comment: Did you run as admin?

Comment: Yes. It is a scheduled task running as admin. It works some times, but not others with no changes.

Comment: The exact script would work fine if called via powershell as a script. It only caused an issue via a scheduled task.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what OS you are (were) running, but I'm going to assume Windows since you don't mention dotNet Core

This might be a CIM-vs-WMI issue, especially where you are querying hardware properties on the Pi. You might get better results using `Get-WMIObject`:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_NetworkAdapter" -Filter "NetConnectionStatus=2"
```

- [Win32_NetworkAdapter class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216(v=vs.85).aspx) describes the possible values for NetConnectionStatus, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this on a Raspberry Pi, but you could shift this logic into a ScriptBlock and run it as a Job (aka a child process) which you could monitor for completion and kill/retry if it takes too long.

Example code:

```
$ResetAdapter = {
    ... your code here ...
}

$job = Start-Job -Name ResetAdapter -ScriptBlock $ResetAdapter

do {
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

  $Elapsed = ((Get-Date)-$job.PSBeginTime).TotalSeconds
} while (($job.State -eq "Running") -and ($Elapsed -lt 60))

if($job.State -eq "Running"){
  Stop-Job $job
  Remove-Job $job

  # try again?
}
```

Comment: I have tried that. Have also tried calling a separate ps1 file in a different thread. Regardless of what I try it hangs. The Powershell.exe process is running and sits at around 25% so I assume something is happening but cant not confirm what.

Comment: You probably need some debugging (logging to file?) to confirm when and where the script is hanging.

Comment: I was. It would simply hang on the get-netadapater. The exact script has no issues if called manually via powershell. It only has an issue if it called via a scheduled task. Task manager shows the task as powershell.exe with 25% CPU. I have ended up giving up and used Linux.

Comment: I know the feeling. Just added another answer. Most likely you're not in a position to test any more, but someone else might stumble across this...